# Make a left Enter key with AutoHotkey, and also with a hot-key to resume the remapped key?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm thinking about to remap some key to behavior the Enter key for the left hand to easy access.

Then I find [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and plan to map the Capslock key to Enter key. Also I need to resume to the Capslock key when I need it, so I also map the RAlt+Capslock to be the Capslock key.

However it doesn't work as expected. Anyone can give some advises?

Here's what I've tried:

```
Capslock::Enter
RAlt & Capslock::SendInput !{Capslock}
```

For now the second line can work but the first line doesn't work. When press the Capslock it doesn't send Enter key.

Comment: `$Capslock::Enter` works for me. The $ makes sure the command only reacts to real capslock presses. RAlt & Capslock doesn't work for me and it gets quite complicated to toggle capslock this way. Better: Use the command `SetCapsLockState` and store the current value internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$CapsLock::Enter
RAlt & Capslock::SetCapsLockState, % GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") ? "Off" : "On"
```

Comment: Hi @Avi Aryan, the Enter can work, but how can I back to the Capslock key

Comment: @Wayou What do you mean by "how can I back to Capslock key". As per your code and question, the above code will **toggle** Capslock when `Ralt & Capslock` is pressed. You should also see the [Hotkey command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) to manage hotkeys at script runtime

Comment: Oh my fault. I take the RAlt as LAlt. Actually I want the LAlt key. I changed it and tested, works like a charm! Thanks man :)

Comment: Always nice to help . Welcome